# How to solve Silverstripe User error Uncaught InvalidArgumentException?

Tags: silverstripe

I am getting error message in silverstripe

> [User Error] Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to parse string: Malformed inline YAML string ({count} {class} saved successfully.).

I have added screenshot of error page.
[image: SS error page]

Comment: You should also add the code as text (code). It seems though your input is causing the problem, could you also share that? (BTW it might make sense to add the [php] tag.)

Comment: @Gábor Bakos thanks for reply, but I am not able to locate the code in which have error. it started appear after I made some changes in SIMPLE theme template file. then I delete that code, but still error not resolve

Comment: You can paste the stack trace here, as text, not image. Also, did you do a flush after changing the theme file?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your reply. it was a YAML parser error. There was a bug in the 'gridfield-bulk-editing-tools' module, I got a help from [silverstripe forum](http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/general-questions/show/102463#post402436)

Comment: Thank you and UncleCheese for the fix for this build error